# Update text file on web server using PHP

Tags: php

I have written a HTML form to collect user's inputs for an order and also a PHP program to receive the order when Submit button is pressed. In addition I got to update a text file stored on the web server to reflect the order items. Can anyone explain how am I to go about updating a text file stored on the server? Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You should lock the file to protect the file from getting clobbered by concurrent updates sent by several users. There is a full example of locking and writing to a file in the `flock` function documentation: http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Or, to save yourself the trouble, use a proper database. SQLite is easy to use and requires no setting up: http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite):

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $yourData);
fclose($fp);
```

**UPDATE:**

If I understood you right you need something like this:

```
if(!empty($noOfApples)){
  $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w+');
  $count=fread($fp,filesize('data.txt'));
  $count+=$noOfApples;
  fwrite($fp, $count);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. But I need to update the text file (example: the number of orders have to be updated each time there is an order). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can create file with order numbers and after getting new order open that file with `fopen` (http://php.net/fread), increase value of file and write again into that file. If I got you then it need to work.

Comment: When you said, "You can create file with order numbers" does that mean that i will have to create a txt file and store default values inside say for example 0 and each time the form is submitted upon typing in the quantity say 3 the value changes from 0 to 3?

But i was wondering how does the text file increment after the form is submitted?Again the form is processed by PHP on submit. 

Your advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: After submitting the form your data saves in `$_POST` variable (if you have method="post" in your form attributes). You just need to check `if(isset($_POST['yourVar'])){/*Do some action*/}`. Update the question with your form HTML code, and I'll send you some simple solution

Comment: This is the code:<?php
 $name = $_POST["User"];
      $noOfApples = $_POST["Apple"];
       if ($noOfApples == "") $noOfApples = 0;
         $apple_cost = 0.69 * $noOfApples;
  ?>
    <h4> Customer Name: </h4>
    <?php
      print ("$name");
    ?>
    <p /> <p />

Comment: <table border = "border">
      <caption> Order Information </caption>
      <tr>
        <th> Product </th>
        <th> Unit Price </th>
        <th> Quantity Ordered </th>
        <th> Item Cost </th>
      </tr><td> Apple </td>
        <td> $0.69 </td>
        <td> <?php print ("$noOfApples"); ?> </td>
        <td> <?php printf ("$ %4.2f", $apple_cost); ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
     
    </table>

Comment: This is the php file. The apples ordered are read from a html file. I need to update the number of apples ordered every time in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this AND preserve array structure of form fields is to dump $_POST via serialize.

Write example, after a user clicks submit:

`file_put_contents('myfile.txt', serialize( $_POST ) );`

Read example:

`$data = unserialize(file_get_contents('myfile.txt'));`

The form field would look something like:

`<input type="text" name="myfield" value="<?php echo $data['myfield'] ?>" />`

Alternatively, you can technically do $_POST = unseralize(file_get_contents(... but it will obviously overwrite anything that a user might input.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the user input with the key which should be the input name and the value which should be the content user input. In this way, you can get the user input in an array.
Then you can translate the key-value pair into a string with `serialize` function. Now you can store the string into file with those code:

```
$fp = fopen('user{$id}.txt', 'w');//replace the {$id} with user id
fwrite($fp, $dateFromUser);
fclose($fp);
```

When you want to show the user input, just read the file and `unserialize` the string you get from the file and fill the input with the data which is stored in the array with the same key. When you want to update the user input just do the process above again.